# How to use the NUL character as a separator in sed substitute and delete commands?

Tags: sed, null

This is what I tried, when intending to replace `/path/to/a` with `/path/to/b` using `NUL` as the separator/delimiter:

```
$ cat pathsList| sed -r -e 's\0/path/to/a\0/path/to/b\0g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: number option to `s' command may not be zero
```

**My wanting to go for `NUL`:** `NUL` and `/` are the only characters that are disallowed on `ext4fs`, and `/` is already used heavily as the pathname separator. Also, I want to avoid quoting and unquoting my data just to be able to used `sed`.

If `NUL` can't be used as a delimiter (let's say), I'll be okay with any workaround better than quoting and unquoting of my data.

```
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.4
```

Comment: could you clarify? this works... `echo "/path/to/a/folder" | sed 's/o/x/g'` .. am not getting why you need any other delimiter here.. perhaps a give a better example?

Comment: as per manual, `Any character other than backslash or newline can be used` as delimiter for `s` command.. however, I don't know how to specify ASCII NUL as delimiter.. may be you have to use some inserting special character trickery on the terminal..

Comment: My example was not about my difficulty in replacing `o` with `x`, rather about my difficulty in using the `NUL` character.

Comment: Your example has no need for a `nul` delimiter in the `sed` expression. Do you have a better example?

Comment: @Kusalananda Edited the example.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like it's possible to use NUL as a separator for the `s///` command in sed.

If you want to create a string with a NUL character in it, you could use the `$'...'` form which bash and other shells recognize, so you might think this would work:

```
sed -r -e $'s\0o\0x\0g'
```

But the way arguments are passed in Linux (and Unix in general) makes it so that it's not really possible to pass strings with embedded NULs, since all you get is an argc (number of arguments) and argv which is an array of `char *`, then NUL-terminated strings (C strings) is the only possible way to take the arguments. In other words, all sed (or any program) will see if passed `$'s\0o\0x\0g'` is simply `"s"` (and the NUL, which they must take as the end of the string.)

I thought perhaps passing that as an external file to sed might work, since in that case sed can know that the NULs are embedded and potentially track the full string by its length, so I tried this:

```
$ cat -v script.sed 
s^@o^@x^@g
```

The `^@`s are the NUL bytes. I inserted them in vim using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> (three zeroes) which is the vim keystroke to enter a character by its ASCII value.

But that doesn't seem to work either:

```
$ echo "/path/to/a/folder" | sed -r -f script.sed 
sed: file script.sed line 1: delimiter character is not a single-byte character
```

Interestingly, that is different from when there's only a single `s` in the script file, in which case sed complains of `unterminated 's' command`... So it seems to be keeping track of the string by its length, but still doesn't look happy to use NUL as its separator character.

Looking at the source code of `sed`, it's unclear whether this was intended or whether it was a bug. In function `is_mb_char()` which tries to detect whether the byte is part of a multi-byte character, handling for NUL [goes like this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=sed.git;a=blob;f=sed/mbcs.c;h=f8e64df82f404cbbf1d380d1b57df932c1423df3;hb=7c8b9abf15d21fec8ade53e04adb20607c8865a2#l57):

```
case 0: /* Special case of mbrtowc(3): the NUL character */
  /* TODO: test this */
  return 1;
```

In this case, `return 1` means "yes, it's a multi-byte char", which is not really the case.

[A comment a few lines above says](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=sed.git;a=blob;f=sed/mbcs.c;h=f8e64df82f404cbbf1d380d1b57df932c1423df3;hb=7c8b9abf15d21fec8ade53e04adb20607c8865a2#l31):

```
/*
 * Return zero in all other cases:
 *   CH is a valid single-byte character (e.g. 0x01-0x7F in UTF-8 locales);
 *   CH is an invalid byte in a multibyte sequence for the currentl locale,
 *   CH is the NUL byte.
 */
```

So perhaps `return 0` was intended?

The [commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=sed.git;a=commitdiff;h=0052daf1e5651c4772d75b595dfc714e0e20587e) which introduced this code doesn't have that much more context here...

The [man page for `mbrtowc(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mbrtowc) mentions `L'\0'` which I assume is some kind of multi-byte NUL, so maybe that's why they decided to handle it this way?

I hope this information is still helpful!

Comment: +1 for taking the time to look into its source and enlightening us about it here. This means, `sed` is broken.

Comment: sed does support \0 as delimiter since 2012 (sed 4.2.2)

Comment: @Ding-YiChen I believe you're talking about using `\0` as a line separator, which is available with the `-z` command-line option and indeed available since 2012. This question is about using `\0` as a separator for a `s/.../.../` or `s#...#...#` command. While it's possible to use characters other than `/`, using a NUL character is not really possible here.

Comment: @filbranden you are right

Answer (score 3):

While NUL can't be found in a file name (for the similar reason it can't be found in a command argument), `.` (very common), `^`, `*`, `[`, `$`, `\` all can and would also have to be escaped anyway as they are regular expression operators understood by `sed`'s `s` command.

[You can always do that *escaping* in an automated fashion](/a/129063).

Note that beside NUL, newline and all multi-byte characters can't be used in GNU `sed` either. Other implementations may have different limitations. POSIX also prohibits backslash (though it works for GNU `sed`), so I would recommend sticking with graphical characters other than backslash from the portable character set.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace single characters (bytes) with single characters (bytes), use `tr`:

```
$ echo "/path/to/a/folder" | tr ao xy
/pxth/ty/x/fylder
```

For arbitrary strings, you could use Perl:

```
$ echo "/path/to/a/folder" | patt=o repl=xx perl -pe 's/$ENV{patt}/$ENV{repl}/g'
/path/txx/a/fxxlder
```

(I passed `patt` and `repl` through the environment, since `perl -p` implies taking the command line arguments as names of files to process.)

Here, of course, `patt` is taken as a regular expression, with everything that implies:

```
$ echo "/path/to/a/folder" | patt='a.' repl=x perl -pe 's/$ENV{patt}/$ENV{repl}/g'
/pxh/to/xfolder
```

So you'll need to either escape the dots (`\.`) and other special characters, or use `\Q$ENV{patt}`:

```
$ echo "/path/to/a/folder.txt" | patt=. repl=, perl -pe 's/\Q$ENV{patt}/$ENV{repl}/g'
/path/to/a/folder,txt
```

---

In both the above cases (command-line arguments and environment variables), the interface between the OS and the utility passes the strings as NUL-terminated strings, as used by the C standard library. This interface makes it impossible to inject literal NUL bytes in the arguments, and `sed -e 's\a\x\g'` has sed use the literal backslash as a separator for the `s` command.

Comment: Perl is not an option for me, but... +1.

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed supports the option `-z` since [2012](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/?id=a08590648922bf13dc73f2d96ba50202556901af).

Example:

```
$ printf 'foo\0bar\0' | sed -z 's/$/!/' | tr '\0' '\n'
foo!
bar!
```

But in most cases it is better to use Perl.

```
$ printf '%s\n' path1 path2 | perl -pe 'BEGIN {($a, $b) = (shift, shift)} s($a){$b}g' 'path' $'some/fance/new/name\t'
some/fance/new/name     1
some/fance/new/name     2
```

Comment: That's for the data not the command(s), but this question was only for the command(s).

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @cerving' is close, but no need to use tr.

```
cat pathsList| sed -z 's/\n/\x0/g'
```

`-z` for using `\x0` as delimiter. It essentially turns your file into a long string (if pathsList does not contain `\x0` already). Thus your file should not be too big to fit the available memory.

Answer (score -2):

You can try if this works:

```
$ echo "/path/to/a/folder" | sed -r -e 's/\0o/\0x/g'
```