# How can I sort sections of file alphabetically?

Tags: text-processing, awk, python, sort

I have a file of several sections, each section start with specific title but all of them ending with the same string, I want to sort the file sections according to the titles without sorting the content of each section (i.e. take the whole section as one block) there is also a blank line between each two section, to clarify the idea if the input is as

```
string5
z
y
x
string

string2
x
z
y
f
string
```

the desired output would be as

```
string2
x
z
y
f
string

string5
z
y
x
string
```

Comment: What are the actual values of `string`, `string2` and `string5`, and may they occur as part of the `x`, `z`, etc.? Are any of the lines within a section empty? Are you sorting on the `2` and `5` in `string2` and `string5`, or on the whole string?

Comment: string2 and string5 are titles containg alot of words strating  with R01, R02, R03 ... etc, while the end of each section "string" is just a word

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using GNU `sed` and `sort`:

```
sed 's/^$/\x0/g' file | sort -z | tr '\0' '\n'
```

- Put null character in empty line
- `sort` using null character as delimiter ( `-z`)
- finally replace null delimiter with new line using `tr`.
- to remove empty lines in first and last line of the output, you may add `| sed '1{/^$/d};${/^$/d}'`

Output:

```
string2
x
z
y
f
string

string5
z
y
x
string
```

(maybe someone can help making `\x0` work for non-GNU `sed`, [related Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459500/how-to-use-the-nul-character-as-a-separator-in-sed-substitute-and-delete-command))

Comment: this just add x0 in the blank line keeping the rest as it is

Comment: interesting, maybe a GNU vs non-GNU thing again o0

Comment: yep was related to GNU vs non-GNU issue

Comment: this adds two empty lines between blocks. for `\x0` if you change to `\o0` might be compatible.

Comment: On OS X, if you want to work around the unsupported `\x0` problem, you can install GNU utils e.g. via Homebrew, and use `gsed` instead of `sed`.

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful, thanks! I also had the non-GNU issue when running my script in Linux Alpine. Ended up solving the problem by installing GNU sed, as described in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957014/alpine-linux-sed-what-is-the-equivalent-of-z-or-null-data-switch-when-usi), in case others face the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU `awk` in paragraph mode and sort the array's values in string mode then print:

```
awk -v RS= '{ seen[NR]=$0 }
END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc";
      for (block in seen) {print sep seen[block]; sep=ORS}
}' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -l -00 -e '
  chomp(@paragraphs = <>);
  print join "\n\n", sort @paragraphs' your-file
```